# Should I track outbound links as a virtual page view, or use an event?

Tags: google-analytics

Looking at the documentation on the web, it seems to be a common practise to track outbound links as a virtual pageview with a URL like `/outgoing/{original_url}`.  But a lot of that documentation is from before Google added events to analytics.  Which is the preferred method nowadays - page views or events?

Comment: Redirection is definitely a lot messier - I'd say avoid it if you can. Redirect link copy/paste doesn't work as expected, and unless you're careful an attacker/griefer can make a link to your site become a goatse...

Comment: @Robert - sorry, I should have made it clear that I meant a virtual pageview.  Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'correct' way is to track outbound links, downloads, etc. as events. - Creating virtual pageviews is a hack, from back when events wasn't released.

Virtual pageview tracking artificially inflates the number of aggregated pageview, and thereby polutes the data, so best-practice is to avoid this if possible.

However, there are cases where virtual-pageview-tracking is the only solution, and thats when you need to track the outbound link (or download etc.) as a goal - and thereby being able to optimize against this goal in AdWords.

Examples include AdWords optimization with regard to PDF-download.

If this is not the case, use event-tracking.

--

A standard snippet is (which simply is included in the specific `<a>`'s `onclick`-attribute):

```
_trackEvent('Outbound link', 'Click', 'http://www.external-link.com', 0)
```

Google has another solution to this:

http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55527

Which tracks the events, waits 100ms and the redirects to the external link - this imo, is not the best solution.

--

Another thing to remember, is that the onclick-event is not fired when the user right-clicks -> open in tab, or the equilivant middle-click.

Comment: In the meantime you can **track the outbound link as a goal**: Just use _Event_ as type for your goal. However it seems, that you can not use it in a funnel (tracking a virtual pageview should work, but increase pageviews). Maybe "Event flow" can be used for something similar to a funnel.